# How do you handle bad requests with RSpec tests in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

In my test database, I have reviews that i am making API calls to in my API-only Rails 5 app.

So far i have written tests for my index and show actions for the ReviewsController.

How do i handle error/bad request handling? For instance, if someone tries to go to a route that doesn't exist or if someone tries to navigate to a show route without an existing id, how is that done in RSpec?

```
# spec/controllers/api/v1/reviews_controller_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Api::V1::ReviewsController do
  describe "GET #index" do
    before do
      get :index
    end

    it "returns HTTP Success" do
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
    end

    it "JSON body response contains expected review attributes" do
      json_response = JSON.parse(response.body)
      json_response["status"].should == "SUCCESS"
    end
  end

  describe "GET #show" do
    before do
      get :show, params: { id: 1 }
    end

    it "returns HTTP Success" do
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
    end

    it "JSON body response contains expected review attributes" do
      json_response = JSON.parse(response.body)
      json_response["status"].should == "SUCCESS"
    end
  end
end
```

ReviewsController:

```
# spec/controllers/api/v1/reviews_controller.rb
module Api
  module V1
    class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
      def index
        @reviews = Review.order(created_at: :desc)
        render json: { status: 'SUCCESS', message: 'loaded reviews', data: @reviews }
      end

      def show
        @review = Review.find(params[:id])
        render json: { status: 'SUCCESS', message: 'loaded the review', data: @review }
      end

      private

      def review_params
        params.require(:review).permit(:title, :star, :content, :name, :date)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You can check if the http status is `:bad_request`.

Answer (score 1):

In a controller test, you can spec that the controller raises an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` when the `id` doesn't exist.

```
describe "GET #show" do
  context "with a valid id" do
    before do
      get :show, params: { id: 1 }
    end

    it "returns HTTP Success" do
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
    end

    it "JSON body response contains expected review attributes" do
      json_response = JSON.parse(response.body)
      json_response["status"].should == "SUCCESS"
    end
  end

  context "with an invalid id" do
    it "raises an error" do
      expect { 
        get :show, params: { id: "invalid-identifier" }
      }.to raise_error ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    end
  end
end
```

Note that when a controller raises an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` in `production` environment then Ruby on Rails will return a `404 (not found)` – if the default was not changed. Read more about this behavior in the [Rails Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#rescue).